# Объявление переменной 24 бит

Tags: c

Мне надо определить переменную состоящую из 24 бит. Так как струтктуры uint24_t нет, я решил использовать битовые поля.

```
struct color24{
    unsigned r : 24;
};

int Color_Led1(void)
{
    struct color24  a;
    a.r = 0x100000; 
    return a.r;
}
```

При компиляции, получаю следующую ошибку:

```
make flash
mkdir -p build/
sdcc -mstm8  -I Libraries/STM8S_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/ -D STM8S003 -o build/ src/main.c 
src/main.c:121: error 31: bit field size cannot be greater than int (16 bits)
make: *** [compile] Ошибка 1
```

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: компилятор для данной платформы не умеет создавать код, который оперирует более чем 16 битами. так что только делить переменную на части и оперировать самому с ее отдельными байтами (максимум 16 битными полями)

Comment: Может `unsigned long` или `unsigned long long` сработает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  не сработало

Comment: Тогда я бы сделал `struct color24 {unsigned char r, g, b;}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, только наверное `uint8_t`, а не `unsigned char`.

Comment: А как вы себе представляете переносимый вариант типа `uint24_t`?

Comment: @0andriy Честно говоря, ни разу не видел систему, где они бы отличались.

Comment: Тогда уж для удобства в структуру засунуть Юнион нужного размера, с разбиением на р,Дж,б

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define RGB(r,g,b)  ((r<<16)|(g<<8)|b)
#define get_RED(color_rgb) (color_rgb>>16)
#define get_GREEN(color_rgb) ((color_rgb>>8)&0xFF)
#define get_BLUE(color_rgb) (color_rgb&0xFF)
#define set_RED(color_rgb,red) (color_rgb=(color_rgb&0x0000FFFF)|(red<<16))
#define set_GREEN(color_rgb,green) (color_rgb=(color_rgb&0x00FF00FF)|(green<<8))
#define set_BLUE(color_rgb,blue) (color_rgb=(color_rgb&0x00FFFF00)|blue)
typedef unsigned int color_rgb;
int main()
{
    color_rgb a = RGB (127,45,213);
    printf("RED %d\nGREEN %d\nBLUE %d\n",get_RED(a),get_GREEN(a),get_BLUE(a));
    set_RED(a,10);
    set_GREEN(a,35);
    set_BLUE(a,153);
    printf("RED %d\nGREEN %d\nBLUE %d\n",get_RED(a),get_GREEN(a),get_BLUE(a));
}
```

Comment: постарался попроще показать как нужно сохранить цвет.

Comment: уже смотри на какой архитектуры работаешь:
1) 32bit/64bit [uint32_t ] - и помни об упаковке структур (3 байта, будут 4 байта для сохранение времени при чтение если не упаковать).
2)16bit - создай 3 байтовый пакет по стандарту копилятора уже.
По твоей проблеме архитектура 16 бит, максимальный арифметический  регистер 16 битный, битовые поля не могут быть загружены в парные регистры. И да на уровне компилятора uint8_t и unsigned char тоже самое, а вот unsigned int и uint32_t не то же самое.

Comment: не думаю что пишешь код для 7 битном контроллере или на 12 битной или 18 битной системе